# Parsing twitter post JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, twitter

I'm trying to parse the data from the Twitter API in PHP, I would like to receive back the image url `media_url_https` but I can't get to it. However, I can get the `text` object fine.

Here's my code:

```
$data=json_encode($twitter_data);

foreach($data as $item) {
    echo $item['text'].'<br/>IMAGE_URL: '.$item['entities']['media']['media_url_https'];
}
```

Here's the JSON I'm trying to parse:

```
[
{
"created_at":"Fri Jun 17 22:24:10 +0000 2016",
"id":743932274996056064,
"id_str":"743932274996056064",
"text":"With a heavy heart... https:\/\/t.co\/Dd1M0b7G1P",
"truncated":false,
"entities":{
"hashtags":[
],
"symbols":[
],
"user_mentions":[
],
"urls":[
],
"media":[
{
"id":743932268314497024,
"id_str":"743932268314497024",
"indices":[
22,
45
],
"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/ClL6dN3WEAAWykw.jpg",
"media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/ClL6dN3WEAAWykw.jpg",
"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/Dd1M0b7G1P",
"display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/Dd1M0b7G1P",
"expanded_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/taylorswift13\/status\/743932274996056064\/photo\/1",
"type":"photo",
"sizes":{
"small":{
"w":680,
"h":519,
"resize":"fit"
},
"thumb":{
"w":150,
"h":150,
"resize":"crop"
},
"medium":{
"w":1200,
"h":915,
"resize":"fit"
},
"large":{
"w":2048,
"h":1562,
"resize":"fit"
}
}
}
]
},
```

I can't see what's wrong, I'm probably missing something simple! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Surely you want json_decode, not json_encode

Comment: @rjdown Using `json_decode` returns the array from Twitter

Comment: Well, that's what you want, isn't it??

Comment: No, I'd like it to echo the object `media_url_https` which in this case is `https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/ClL6dN3WEAAWykw.jpg`

Comment: You need to decode the data into an object first. That's what json_decode does.

Comment: I have just changed my code to use `json_decode` and it just echos `$item['text']` not `$item['entities']['media']['media_url_https']`

Comment: You need to pass true as the second parameter if want an array (instead of an object). I strongly recommend reading the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php then try `var_dump($item);` You'll have a better idea of what you need to echo.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a read, thanks